# Dystopian SF movie with a parallel world, a jungle and strange robot

Tags: story-identification, movie

I watched this somewhere in 2011.

A kid entered a door and he was taken to a different parallel universe. He was captured by some kids his age that lived in a jungle in a small castle thing.

They later became his friends and the real enemies were the government who caught those kids and put them in a machine and turned them into grown men to fight for the government. (Sort of like in *The Avengers* where Captain America was transformed into a muscular man, only they were transformed into grown men from children.)

The government also had an arena where they put enemies there like the children, and they had to fight this huge metal circle ball robot with tentacles. Later in the movie the protagonist (the kid) finds the control room of the robot and destroys their arena or their city.

In the end he returns to the real world and cries because nobody believes him in what happened .

(It's not *Narnia*.)

Comment: Was this a live-action movie or animated?

Comment: Live-action movie.

Comment: How that castle looked like? Could you describe that circle-ball robot and a control room?

Comment: We don't remember.  But we are sure that protagonist ( the boy ) found a big egg on the ground and helped to put it in its nest on a tall mountain where and turns out the egg belonged to some sort of phoenix big bird